# sublime text identation check by plugin

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing my first simple sublime text 3 plugin.
It's purpose is adding always true if statements to the precompilled code for avoiding of parser stack overflowing in the another ide.

Now it's looking for closest end if at the ofset and adding it's own end if, BUT it's making it at any end if line.

```
  if (1=1)
%Layout__control__IDs[$Layout__control__count] := $Layout__Unit7Control3LabelID
%Layout__control__types[$Layout__control__count] := 3
if (1=1)
  %Layout__Page__IDs[$Layout__control__count] := $Layout__Unit7Control3LabelID
  %Layout__control__Page[$Layout__control__count] := $Layout__Page__count
end if
  here is plugin inserted string
  HEYEND
    !Layout__control__names[$Layout__control__count] := "Unit7Control3Label"
    !Layout__LabelsNames[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := "Unit7Control3Label"
    add_menu_item($Layout__control,"Unit7Control3Label",$Layout__control__count)
    if (%Layout__LabelsAssigned[search(%Layout__LabelsIDs,$Layout__Unit7Control3LabelID)]=0)
      %Layout__LabelsX[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := -1
      %Layout__LabelsY[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := -1
    end if
    %Layout__LabelsW[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := -1
    %Layout__LabelsH[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := -1
    !Layout__LabelsTexts[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := ""
    %Layout__LabelsTextAl[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := 0
    %Layout__LabelsFont[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := 0
    %Layout__LabelsTextPosY[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := 0
    !Layout__LabelsImgs[$Layout__LabelsIDsCount] := ""
    inc($Layout__LabelsIDsCount)
    inc($Layout__control__count)
  end if
```

How can i check the identation amount of end if line to avoid this?

plugin code:

```
    import sublime, sublime_plugin
class PrefixrCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # find string with 'on init'
        startreg = self.view.find("on init", 0)
        # make int to tuple obj with row and col nr 
        start = startreg.end()
        # find the end of 'init'
        InitEndReg = self.view.find("end on", start)
        InitEnd = InitEndReg.end()
        # get tuple obj with row & col
        StartRowCol = self.view.rowcol(start)
        StartRowCol += (1000,0)
        ofset = self.view.text_point(StartRowCol[0]+StartRowCol[2],0)
        # if ofset < end on
        if InitEnd > ofset:
            # add string to the start point
            self.view.insert(edit, start, "\nHEYSTART\n")
            # find 'end if' region after ofset
            EndIfReg = self.view.find("end if", ofset)
            EndIf = EndIfReg.end()
            EndIfReg = self.view.full_line (EndIf)
            EndIf = EndIfReg.end()
            self.view.insert(edit, EndIf, "\nHEYEND\n")
            StartWhileRowCol = self.view.rowcol(EndIf)
            StartWhileRowCol += (2,0)
            StartWhile = self.view.text_point(StartWhileRowCol[0]+StartWhileRowCol[2],0)
            # получаем tuple объект с номером строки и буквы
            StartRowCol = self.view.rowcol(StartWhile)
            # типа увеличиваем номер строки на 1000, на самом деле добавляя еще два элемента к объекту
            StartRowCol += (1000,0)
            # добавляем первый номер строки ко второму (1000)
            ofset = self.view.text_point(StartRowCol[0]+StartRowCol[2],0)
        while InitEnd > ofset:
            if InitEnd > ofset:
                # добавляем строку в начало "итерации"
                self.view.insert(edit, StartWhile, "\nHEYSTART\n")
                # ищем регион с end if после строки офсета
                EndIfReg = self.view.find("end if", ofset)
                # переводим ее в tuple объект для вызова функции API
                EndIf = EndIfReg.end()
                EndIfReg = self.view.full_line (EndIf)
                EndIf = EndIfReg.end()
                # вставляем строку после end if
                self.view.insert(edit, EndIf, "\nHEYEND\n")
                StartWhileRowCol = self.view.rowcol(EndIf)
                StartWhileRowCol += (2,0)
                StartWhile = self.view.text_point(StartWhileRowCol[0]+StartWhileRowCol[2],0)
                # получаем tuple объект с номером строки и буквы
                StartRowCol = self.view.rowcol(StartWhile)
                # типа увеличиваем номер строки на 1000, на самом деле добавляя еще два элемента к объекту
                StartRowCol += (1000,0)
                # добавляем первый номер строки ко второму (1000)
                ofset = self.view.text_point(StartRowCol[0]+StartRowCol[2],0)
```